# Are JavaScript functions objects?

Tags: javascript, function, object, typeof

If JavaScript functions are first class objects and therefore of type object why does the below happen?

```
function hello(){}
typeof hello -> function
```

should it not give

```
typeof hello -> object
```

Comment: @JJJ I saw it and tried to find a better duplicate but couldn't. That question is pretty different from this one. If you find a better duplicate I'm definitely in favor of dupehammering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, JavaScript functions are objects. The only base types in JavaScript are the primitive value types: number, symbol, boolean, null, undefined and string and objects.

Everything that is not a primitive value type is an object. `typeof` is broken for other reasons, for example `typeof null` is "object" but null is in fact not an object.

`typeof hello` returns function because it's probably the only way to really be sure something can be called as a function.

Comment: cool cheers. so is typeof unsafe to use?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp

This article may be able to give you more information if you are interested.

Comment: @Theworm `typeof` is safe to use if you understand all its caveats.

Answer (score 1):

**In Javascript, if it's not a primitive, it's an object.** Unfortunately, javascript does not distinguish very well between arrays, functions, and null when using the `typeof` operator, but there are ways to tell by using `Object.prototype.call()`

Here is an example:

```js
var a = function () {};
var b = null;
var c = [];
var d = {};
console.log("typeof function () {}: " + typeof a + " -- Object.prototype: " + Object.prototype.toString.call(a));
console.log("typeof null: " + typeof b + " -- Object.prototype: " + Object.prototype.toString.call(b));
console.log("typeof []: " + typeof c + " -- Object.prototype: " + Object.prototype.toString.call(c));
console.log("typeof {}: " + typeof d + " -- Object.prototype: " + Object.prototype.toString.call(d));
```

Comment: You can cheat `Object.prototype.toString.call` for a while now using `Symbol.toStringTag`. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

While Javascript functions are objects, so are numbers, strings, etc. The typeof function lets you know when the object is a specific data structure that Javascript already knows, and returns object if it's one that it doesn't know (but is still defined/not null).

There's more about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof